# Desenvolver em Python com Visual Studio 2013

Tags: python, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio, ide

Estou querendo desenvolver em Python usando o Visual Studio 2013 ou 2015 pois já estou acostumado com a IDE, mas não tenho experiência com a linguagem.
No SO em inglês há [uma questão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python) que lista o Visual Studio como IDE mas muitos recursos estão como *'a confirmar' ("?")*.

De acordo com essa mesma tabela, alguém poderia me dizer quais desses recursos estão disponíveis no Visual Studio?

Comment: A título pessoal as IDE's que costumo usar para Python são: - [Atom](https://atom.io/) - [IDLE](https://docs.python.org/2/library/idle.html) (já vem por defeito com Python) - [gedit](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit) (já vem por defeito com ubuntu) Prefiro essas IDEs porque conseguem ser simples e ao mesmo tempo com uma baixa curva de aprendizagem inicial. Quanto ao Visual Studio nunca o utilizei para Python.

Comment: Tem também o PyCharm (https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/); em termos de python no VS, só conheço Iron Python(http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2009/10/25/hosting-ironpython-in-a-c-4-0-program.aspx) - provavelmente não é isso q vc precisa. Eu não tinha ouvido falar ainda em desenvolver nativamente em python no VS.

Comment: Verificarei essas IDE's mas como estou acostumado com o VS considerei usa-lo (http://microsoft.github.io/PTVS/). Por isso gostaria de uma resposta que abordasse mais detalhes de desenvolvimento com o VS, se eu ficaria limitado e em quais pontos. A partir disso irei considerar outras IDE's, caso exista muitas limitações.

Comment: George, eu gostei da sua pergunta e acho que ela é válida e importante para o site. Porém a última parte (onde tu pede indicações) dá a entender que as respostas seriam baseadas em opiniões, remova essa parte para que a pergunta não seja fechada.

Comment: @jbueno, obrigado pela dica. Removi a parte solicitada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O [Python Tools for Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/python-vs.aspx) te atende?

Ele já vem com o VS 2015 (talvez você tenha que habilitar na sua instalação) e pode ser [instalado](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/PTVS-Installation) sobre o VS 2013, ou mesmo VS 2010 e 2012.

Comment: Já tenho um VS2015 em um computador e já até testei o Python Tools nele, só não consegui comparar ainda com outras IDEs, pois meu conhecimento em Python é bem fraco ainda. Mas é oque melhor me atende sim. Obrigado!